# 'SOL_SOCKET' undeclared (first use in this function) while installing collectd in RHEL6

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, collectd

I am trying to install collectd on RHEL6. While running 'make', i am facing the below issue.

```
error:
network.c: In function 'network_bind_socket':
network.c:1854: error: 'SOL_SOCKET' undeclared (first use in this function)
network.c:1854: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
network.c:1854: error: for each function it appears in.)
network.c:1854: error: 'SO_REUSEADDR' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[3]: *** [network_la-network.lo] Error 1
```

The getsockopt() specifies  be included and i have added `<sys/socket.h>` header in the 'network.c', still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: did you add `#include <sys/types.h>` also?

Comment: Please post line 1854 in network.c, or a range of lines that include 1854.

Comment: @Sourav I tried that too but same issue..

Comment: @Tony Here is the funtion 'network_bind_socket' in 'network.c'

`static int network_bind_socket (int fd, const struct addrinfo *ai, const int interface_idx)
{
#if KERNEL_SOLARIS
char loop   = 0;
#else
int loop = 0;
#endif
int yes  = 1;

if (setsockopt (fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,&yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) {
char errbuf[1024];
ERROR ("network plugin: setsockopt (reuseaddr): %s", sstrerror (errno, errbuf, sizeof (errbuf)));
return (-1);
}`

Comment: First of all, I assume you ran "configure"... Additionally, I see that network.c has the include of <sys/socket.h>  within an "#ifdef HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H "... can you check config.h and confirm the the following is present: "#define HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H 1"

Comment: Yes i ran "configure" before running "make" and "#define HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H 1" entry is there in config.h

Comment: I'm sorry to say but I'm at a loss... the error is symptomatic of <sys/socket.h> not being included, or on your platform SOL_SOCKET and SO_REUSEADDR not being present in "sys/socket.h" (or a file it may include).  I would try to pursue it from that point of view... first are those defines present???  Then, write a stub program with only a "setsockopt(1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &some_int, sizeof(some_int));", in the main, and see if it will compile... if so, then track down why it isn't being included in network.c (perhaps run the preprocessor to see what it is outputting).

Comment: Great it worked. Those defines were missing in <bits/socket.h> which is present in <sys/socket.h>.. Thanks @Tony